# What would happen if the brain disappeared only for microseconds in a human being?

Tags: science-based, humans, death

Will the person live if his/her brain disappeared only for microseconds?

> Disappearing only for microseconds means absent for microseconds &
>   it reappears again in its original state.

Comment: Are neural connections to rest of the body reattached after being severed? What about vacuum created when brain disappears? Does it cause boiling of cerebrospinal fluid or other lasting damage? Will reappearance cause damage because of problems with displacement of vapours taking place of former vacuum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brain is an ***electro***-chemical device; meaning it also depends on electrical fields. If the matter of the brain disappears, presumably the unattached electrical fields do not; they will dissipate in microseconds.

Remember a microsecond is 1000 nanoseconds; light, at 186,282 miles per second, can travel 983.6 feet in one microsecond, or 0.19 miles. Although electrical fields in materials tend to travel around 2/3 the speed of light, a "few microseconds" is more than enough time for them to dissipate.

However, microseconds will not be enough time for blood and other fluids to move very much at all; and I will presume the return position is exact to the molecular level; so no severing of nerves occurs. I will also presume the magical disappearance and reappearance do not create an absolute vacuum that causes the head to implode; although I doubt even that could be completed in microseconds (it is just air pressure that causes the implosion) we will handwave away the fact that it might start. In order to reappear in the skull as the OP obviously intends, the skull cannot be deformed by the beginning of a head implosion.

That said, when the brain returns in its "original" state, it is likely to be devoid of any electrical signals in progress. The person will most likely be unconscious; and may not recover (this might kill them). Their brain would need an electrical reboot; that might occur through natural action of blood moving through the brain because of the beating heart, but might not. In fact the lack of electrical signal in the part of the brain controlling the heart beat might cause a heart attack; the cycle of charges in the brain would have been disrupted by the brain vanishing, and have a cascade effect, even though the vanishing was momentary.

As an analogy, imagine a baseball game in which the first baseman vanishes for a tiny moment, just enough to fail to catch a ball that would otherwise have ended the World Series. The first baseman may be fine, but history is changed, tens of millions of dollars in bets goes to what would have been losers, and is taken from what would have been winners. The point of this analogy is this: The vanishing of the baseball player causes a domino effect of major changes.

The same can be true for the momentary vanishing of the brain; it could easily lead to death by interrupting (and perhaps halting) various cycles of electro-chemical charges that are constantly moving through the brain. In fact we call them brainwaves, detectable purely by their electrical activity, as detected by [Electroencephalography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography).

Comment: The brain does not control the heart by a continuous sequence of pulses for each heart beat. It sends a slower / faster signal over a pair of nerves responsible for the fight or flight response. The heart will hardly bat an eye on the disappearance of that signal for a tiny fraction of the period. One does not simply get a heart attack from falling into coma.  Not to mention that the firing frequency of a neuron is way below 1 kHz,  so the signal can't even disappear for one millisecond.

Comment: I also can't see why the brain should reset electrically. It would take a really picky teleporter to move the neurons and glions and discard the neurotransmitters or displace them outside their synapses  (which would way more devastating than you imply anyways).

Comment: @JanDvorak I guess this requires an interpretation of what counts as "brain," and what does not. I don't think free electrons or a magnetic field count as part of the brain; If they do one must transport much more than the brain, because they extend past the skull. At what point does the spinal cord stop being part of the brain? is blood in a vein part of the brain? Why should neurotransmitters in gaps, touching no part of a synapse, be considered part of the brain? Plus the point wasn't a tiny absence of signal, but the permanent absence of signal **due** to an interruption of a cycle.

Comment: I take it your answer boils down to "teleporting the brain away and back would probably reset its function, which means coma, which means death (because the heart needs supervision)"?

Comment: @JanDvorak No. For one I said "might", I also said it might spontaneously recover, and I also said there are numerous brain waves occurring in cycles that might be disrupted. You are trying to oversimplify what I said to the point of absurdity and I reject that absurdity. I think many things could go wrong with the electrical fields in the brain if the mass were momentarily divorced from all signals in flight, including fatal things. you have made your opinion clear and my position will not change. Comments are not the place for arguments, and I do not wish to continue this one.

Comment: The electrical reboot of the brain is observed in coming out of deep hypothermia or deep anesthesia.

Comment: @Joshua I don't think the brain was devoid of ALL electrical signals in that time, for those conditions. But if it was, that is evidence for my thought that the brain might spontaneously recover. I imagine people coming out of these states are not instantly conscious, however.

Comment: The brain waves do flatline in deep anesthesia. I don't know how fast the brain can come out of it, because the causes are pretty slow to reverse.

Comment: **You totally misunderstand how brain signals work.** If your brain were to be put in an electric dampening field that somehow inhibited all electrical impulses for a split second, you would not die. In fact, the electric fields would reappear _instantly_ due to polarization or depolarization of the axon.